# Having trouble with JSFiddle and basic javascript

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I am trying to use JSFiddle to get a rudimentary base case working and then expand out from it. However, I must be doing something wrong, because I can't even get the js and html windows to work. So here is the code that works. All in the html window:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("The fiddle is working.");
}
</script>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If I take the function and pop it down into the JS window (with the selector on the window set to LoadType of on Dom Ready. I get a console error of:

Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined......

Can someone tell me what silly thing I am missing in order to save me from self-immolation today? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `onclick` attributes. Use `addEventListener`.

Comment: It works for me, https://jsfiddle.net/e81bcfwr/

Comment: Sorry JOSEFtw, the code above works. Moving the function to the bottom fiddle js fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: Quentin - If this is a duplicate I can't find it so please provide the link. And onclick is still a valid html call so your answer is not correct.